# Does the Personal Refiner have a suggested inventory/slot to be installed?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Just unlocked the **Personal Refiner**, and while installing it a note stated that if I place it near the right items I can improve it, or something like that.

So, is there a suggested inventory or slot to install the Refiner? Which items make a synergy with it?

**UPDATE**:

I managed to find a screenshot of that hint!

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot with such  "a note" ? [Wiki](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Upgrade_bonus) doesn't list [Portable refiner](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Portable_Refiner) (though wiki is outdated in many places) and I don't recall I found anything with synergy to it, so very likely the answer is "No". Btw, you can easily reposition installed tech (also between normal and technology tab), so install straight anywhere.

Comment: @Sinatr unfortunately no, I don't have a screenshot ot that message. I've done a lot of research with no luck. Btw my game is in Italian, so it may be just a misleading translation.